# How can I easily back out part of a changeset?

Tags: mercurial

I've previously (i.e. several changesets ago) committed a fairly big changeset that contains both good changes I'd like to keep, and some I'd like to undo. Yes, I shouldn't have packed so much into a single changeset anyway, but now the damage is done.

AFAIK, Mercurial's backout command can only work on an entire changeset. I can certainly figure out how to do this manually in a few steps, but I'm wondering: is there an easy way of getting only *part* of a changeset reversed?

(If it matters, the changes I'd like to undo are file deletions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have tried before posting, but this may be useful for others as well:

Backout doesn't automatically commit. So the approach that worked for me is to run hg backout, then simply revert the files that I don't want to be changed back.

Answer (score 1):

Depending from conditions (amount of "must-be-backout'ed" and "must be preserved" or file-patterns for both cases) you can use `hg backout` with -I (include mask) or -X (exclude mask) option

- `hg backout -r CSET -I FILE` backout **only changes for** FILE
- `hg backout -r CSET -X FILE` backout **all changes except in** FILE

Comment: Thanks, that looks very useful. In my case it was easier to just point-and-click files in the TortoiseHg workbench, but in some scenarios the pattern approach is probably very handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to undo file deletions, then it would be better to use `hg revert` instead of `hg backout`:

```
hg status --change CSET --removed -n0 | xargs -0 hg revert --rev CSET^1
```